# Skype autostart can't be disabled?

Tags: windows-10, boot, skype

Skype appears to have done something to prevent stopping it from auto-running on startup. There is no longer a setting to prevent it from starting on boot. The settings that remain mean I can hide it from the tray (but they still run it in the background -- it's got 4 processes in task manager: Skype > SkypeBridge, Runtime Broker, SkypeApp, Microsoft Skype).

It no longer appears in "start-up" tab of task manager either.

I only use it occassionally, but it's a pain logging out because then one has to find one's password making quickly contacting someone a pretty rubbish UX.

Are Microsoft really that evil, or did they move the setting somewhere and I've missed it? I just want to use Skype when I want to run it, and not have Microsoft control when it gets run, is that asking too much? Is the only route now to delete it and force my elderly relatives to use something else?

(Are there other apps they're shadow running?)

Windows 10, Skype version 8.42.0.60

Comment: I don't see an option either.  One workaround might be to forcibly sign out of Skype and sign back in when it's time to use it again.  It sucks, I know...

Comment: From that Q @Run5k: "In other words, Skype UWP users simply need to logoff from within the app to prevent it from starting automatically during a subsequent Windows 10 login." -- so it looks like that's the only way to do it.This is probably a dupe of that question (didn't show up when I searched??). I'm not having an app I can't choose when to run, looks like I'll need to find an alternative (tbh it's been a pita for my relatives, hope we can settle on something better).

Comment: Yes, but right after that quote it also says *"As a potentially viable alternative to the Skype Community Moderator's advice, you can turn off the background app functionality for Skype,"* and then it explains exactly how to do that.  Something to consider.  That being said, we are always glad to help but yes, this is definitely a duplicate of that question and it might be prudent to mark it accordingly.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've turned off background apps, I don't really trust them at this point not to simply hide Skype from the task manager list, so in view of that I've uninstalled -- thanks for your help though.